# ¿Cómo realizar conteos simultáneos en un mismo Timer?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

El usuario ingresa los datos de la persona a la aplicación con un tiempo específico y este activa un `timer` el `timer` le resta a este tiempo hasta llegar a cero y arroja el mensaje. Mi problema es al ingresar una nueva persona el `timer` se reinicia con el valor de esta nueva persona. Aquí esta el código del `timer` es muy sencillo:

```
seg -= 1;
if (seg == 0 && minutos > 0) {
  minutos -= 1;
  seg = 60;
} 
if (minutos == 0 && seg == 0) {
  timer1.Stop(); 
  MessageBox.Show("Se Ha acabado el tiempo");
}
```

¿Cómo podría llevar el control de estas personas?

Comment: Harolo agrega código  sobre lo que tienes desarrollado y lo que piensas hacer para que sea mas entendible tu problema.

Comment: Por que un solo `Timer`? Por que no crear un `Timer` por usuario?

Comment: que tipo de aplicacion se trata, es asp.net o winform? entiendo que cada persona inicia la aplicacion, o sea no es el mismo proceso, por lo tanto las variables son independientes

Comment: Cierto @LeandroTuttini, asumí que era winforms ya que si no no existiría el problema, pero el OP no lo aclara

Comment: Harolo, aclara primero si es winforms o asp. En cuanto a que no sabes cuantos van a ingresar,eso no es problema. Generas los timers a medida que vayan ingresando por código, no en tiempo de diseño.

Comment: Pero persona = instancia aplicacion ? porque tienes un .exe que alguien ejecuta en su pc, como puede esto controlar a otras personas que ejecutas el mismo .exe en otras PCs. Hay alguna forma de comunicacion entre estas aplicaciones por la red?

Comment: Hay algo muy raro en la arquitectura de lo que describis. Por favor, aclara bien como es la arquitectura. Los usuarios entran a diferentes ejecuciones del programa, que no deberian compartir un timer.

Comment: No solo es no el usuario ingresa los datos de la persona a la aplicacion con un tiempo especifico y este activa un timer el timer le resta a este tiempo  hasta llegar a cero y arroja el mensaje. Mi problema es al ingresar una nueva persona el timer se reinicia con el valor de esta nueva persona. Aqui esta el codigo del timer es muy sencillo: seg -= 1;if (seg == 0 && minutos > 0) { minutos -= 1;seg = 60;} if (minutos == 0 && seg == 0) { timer1.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("Se Ha acabado el tiempo");
            }

Comment: AHHH pero nada que ver lo que planteas ahi.. vos tenes un solo programa, donde se ingresan usuarios, y vos queres un timer por cada uno de esos usuarios que se ingresan ahi no??? bueno, borremos todos los comentarios,usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda esa informacion correcta (es un solo programa, los usuarios que se ingresan son nombres, no son otras personas lanzando el programa), agrega el codigo que intentaste.. y ahi vamos para adelante..

Comment: Como te digo, creas una lista de Timers, y cada vez que se ingrese una nueva persona, añades un timer, y cuando un timer acabe lo quitas de la lista

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu pregunta sigue siendo confusa, podria estar mejor redactada, pero entre todos los comentarios se entiende que tenes un solo programa, donde queres que un operador cargue nombre de usuarios y tiempos para que el timer se dispare.

Esto no se puede hacer con un solo timer. Lo mejor, es crear timers en tiempo de ejecucion e ir controlandolos.

Para ello, vamos a cambiar algunas partes de tu codigo:

Primero, a modo de ejemplo, un form que hace todo lo que vos queres. Tenes que agregar en un form un boton, un label, un listbox y un timer (que se va a usar en el ejemplo para disparar nuevos timers) y el siguiente codigo:

```
List<Timer> ListaTimers = new List<Timer>();
Random r = new Random();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TimerGeneral.Start();
}

private void TimerGeneral_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = r.Next(1000,10000);
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.Interval = i;
    t.Tick += EventoTimer;
    ListaTimers.Add(t);
    t.Start();
    label1.Text = "CANTIDAD DE TIMERS ANDANDO: " + ListaTimers.Count;
}

private void EventoTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer t = (Timer)sender;
    t.Stop();
    listBox1.Items.Add("timer parado de: " + t.Interval);
    ListaTimers.Remove(t);
}
```

Para que esto funcione, conecta el boton al evento click y el tick del timer al evento tick.

La idea que te muestro ahi, es como si alguien cargara muchos timers distintos, por codigo, y estos timers solos se disparan cuando terminan.

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.Interval = i;
t.Tick += EventoTimer;
ListaTimers.Add(t);
```

Aca se crea un nuevo timer, se le pone un intervalo, se conecta el evento EventoTimer, para que se ejecute cuando el timer termine, y se lo agrega a una lista. Esto es importante, porque si no el timer, al ser una variable de esta funcion, se va a perder.

Entonces, lo que vos tenes que hacer, es asignar a tu timer, la cantidad de tiempo que cada usuario requiera. Tu lista, `List<Timer>`, prodia tranquilamente ser una lista mas especializada, por ejemplo conteniendo una clase con el timer, un usuario, el tiempo y otras cosas.

Comment: Se noto que soy novato, Te agradezco mucho no es exactamente lo que necesita pero me sirvio mucho para lo que estaba buscando te agradezco